# call less.js function in javascript has different output in compare node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, less

during this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199473/how-do-you-call-a-less-js-function) i want to call some less functions such as darken, lighten and spin inside javascript. i did it in node.js like this and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var less = require('less');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

less.render(".my{ color:lighten("+ args[0]+","+args[1]+"%); }", function (e, css) {
     console.log(css.match(/\#[0-9a-fA-F]+/)[0]);
});
```

this is output:

```
$ ./my "#000" 13.5
#222222
```

but i did in html and less.js file and using solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199473/how-do-you-call-a-less-js-function) and made this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="less-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var lessColor = {
            /*
             |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Lighten
             |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
             */
            lighten: function (col, val) {
                col = col.replace(/#/g, '');    //Remove the hash

                var color = new less.tree.Color(col);   //Create a new color object
                var amount = new less.tree.Value(val);      //Create a new amount object
                var newRGB = less.tree.functions.lighten(color, amount); //Get the new color
                var hex = (newRGB.rgb[0] + 256 * newRGB.rgb[1] + 65536 * newRGB.rgb[2]).toString(16);
                hex = hex.split('.', 1);    //Remove everything after the decimal if it exists

                //Add padding to the hex to make it 6 characters
                while (hex.length < 6) {
                    hex = hex + '0';
                }
                hex = '#' + hex;  //Add the hash

                return hex; //return the color
            }
        };
        console.log(lessColor.lighten("#000",13.5));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but different output in console:
[image]

i'm pretty sure #222222 is correct result but how can i get this result inside javascript?

Comment: Built-in Less functions usually use [internal Less objects](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/tree/color.js) as arguments - *not* hex rgb strings or simple JS nubers. (So the correct method to call those is something like `less.tree.functions.lighten(new less.tree.Color('#000'), less.tree.Dimension(13.5))`.

Comment: i did your solution http://codepad.org/yQZ4tdvf and it's my output: http://axgig.com/images/43200432572144438170.jpg  it's not hex code

Comment: Make your balancing for opening and closing parens (Sorry I only gave an idea of how it should be used not an exact ready-to-use code snippet).

Comment: Here's correct syntax: `less.tree.functions.lighten(new less.tree.Color('123'), new less.tree.Dimension(13.5))` but note that the function also returns `less.tree.Color` object and not an rgb string/array.

Comment: Thanks so i should looking for a way to convert this color object to hex

Comment: I think `newRGB.toCSS()` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

As can be read from the comments the following code will give you `#222222`:

```
   var lessColor = {
        lighten: function (color, amount) {
        color = new (less.tree.Color)(color.substring(1));
        amount = new(less.tree.Dimension)(amount, '%');
        return less.tree.functions.lighten(color, amount).toRGB(); 
        }
    };
    console.log(lessColor.lighten('#000',13.5));
```

Notice that `color.substring(1)` just like `col.replace(/#/g, '');` removes the starting `#`. The input of less.tree.Color is the hex color triplet the less parser uses the following code for that conversion:

```
var rgb;
if (parserInput.currentChar() === '#' && (rgb = parserInput.$re(/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})/))) {
var colorCandidateString = rgb.input.match(/^#([\w]+).*/); // strip colons, brackets, whitespaces and other characters that should not definitely be part of color string
colorCandidateString = colorCandidateString[1];
if (!colorCandidateString.match(/^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$/)) { // verify if candidate consists only of allowed HEX characters
error("Invalid HEX color code");
}
return new(tree.Color)(rgb[1]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer should be corrected for the newer version of Less.
There is no more `less.tree.functions.lighten`. You should use `less.functions.functionRegistry.get('lighten')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the answer from @Bass Jobsen
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811314/3027390

In modern versions of Less there is no more `less.tree.functions.lighten`.

You should use `less.functions.functionRegistry.get('lighten')` instead.

That applies to any other Less function (not only color).

So, the updated answer should look like:

```
var lessColor = {
    lighten: function (color, amount) {
        color = new (less.tree.Color)(color.substring(1));
        amount = new (less.tree.Dimension)(amount, '%');
        func = less.functions.functionRegistry.get('lighten');
        return func(color, amount).toRGB(); 
    }
};

console.log(lessColor.lighten('#000', 13.5)); // => '#222222'
```